# Calculated column based on current Month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a dataframe in which I want to add a calculated column "Status" based on two columns "DATE" and "Delivery_Date" (Datatype: datetime64[ns])

```
Eg. if(DATE & Delivery_Date contains current month) then (status = yes)
    else (status = no)

   DATE        ||  Delivery_Date    ||      Status
===================================================
01-03-2018     ||   01-08-2018      ||        No
---------------------------------------------------
01-08-2018     ||   30-08-2018      ||        yes
---------------------------------------------------
10-08-2018     ||   28-08-2018      ||        yes
---------------------------------------------------
01-05-2018     ||   31-05-2018      ||        No
---------------------------------------------------
```

I have used a method (given below) to get the current month:

```
from datetime import datetime

currentMonth = datetime.now().month
currentYear = datetime.now().year
```

I have tried:

```
conditions = [(df_new_status['DATE'] == datetime.now().month) & (df_new_status['Delivery_Date'] == datetime.now().month)]
choices = ['Yes']
df_new_status['status'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='No')

(TypeError: invalid type comparison)
```

Comment: Adding more details would let us help you better. Which libraries are you using?

Comment: I would suspect this has to do with the fact that your `DATE` is a full date that you are trying to compare against a month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `datetime` module, you can use the methods available to Pandas. This is especially true since your columns are already in `datetime` format. You can use `pd.Series.dt.month` with `numpy.where` for a single condition:

```
this_month = pd.to_datetime('today').month  # e.g. 8 for August

m1 = df['DATE'].dt.month == this_month
m2 = df['Delivery_Date'].dt.month == this_month

df['status'] = np.where(m1 & m2, 'Yes', 'No')
```

Comment: Great solution @jpp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['Status'] = 'No'
df.loc[(df_new_status['DATE'].dt.month == datetime.now().month) & (df_new_status['Delivery_Date'].dt.month == datetime.now().month), 'Status'] = 'Yes'
```

I think you got that error because your comparing a series (df['DATE']) and an int currentMonth

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
df['Status'] = np.where(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month == pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Delivery_Date']).month, 'Yes', 'No')
```

Output:

```
         Date Delivery_Date  Status
0  01-03-2018    01-08-2018     No
1  01-08-2018    30-08-2018     Yes
2  10-08-2018    28-08-2018     Yes
3  01-05-2018    31-05-2018     Yes
```

Based on JPP's understanding, I am also providing another solution:

```
df['Status'] = np.where((pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month == pd.to_datetime('today').month) & (pd.to_datetime('today').month == pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Delivery_Date']).month), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Output:

```
     Date     Delivery_Date  Status
0  01-03-2018    01-08-2018     No
1  01-08-2018    30-08-2018     Yes
2  10-08-2018    28-08-2018     Yes
3  01-05-2018    31-05-2018     No
```

Comment: Oops. I confused current month with the fact that if delivery date's month has the same month as the date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
test = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['01-03-2018', '01-08-2018'], 'Del_Date': ['01-08-2018', '30-08-2018']})
test['DATE'] =test['DATE'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y'))
test['Del_Date'] =test['Del_Date'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y'))
test
    DATE        Del_Date
0   2018-03-01  2018-08-01
1   2018-08-01  2018-08-30

test['Status'] = test.apply(lambda x: x['DATE'].month == x['Del_Date'].month, axis=1)
test
    DATE        Del_Date    Status
0   2018-03-01  2018-08-01  False
1   2018-08-01  2018-08-30  True
```

This will give you a True or False instead of Yes and No. You could rename them later if you wish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No need for `lambda` functions at all here when you have `datetime` series. `map` + `lambda` is just a thinly veiled loop.

Comment: @jpp totally agreed. I only replicated the steps to show how i created the dataframe.